# What is the dollar sign $ in rails log mean for SQL?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, logging

I'm having trouble understanding why there is a `$1` instead of `123`, which is the `id` I put in.

```
Foo Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "foos".* FROM "foos" WHERE "foos"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 123]]
Doorkeeper::Application Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "oauth_applications".* 
  FROM "oauth_applications" WHERE "oauth_applications"."id" IN (SELECT DISTINCT "oauth_access_tokens"."application_id" 
  FROM "oauth_access_tokens" WHERE "oauth_access_tokens"."resource_owner_id" = $1
  AND "oauth_access_tokens"."revoked_at" IS NULL)  [["resource_owner_id", 123]]
```

Comment: It marks a parameter. The name and value of the parameter are in the brackets at the end. You passed `123` as the value to the first parameter, which is named `id`, in the first example. You passed `123` as well to the first parameter named `resource_owner_id` in the second example.

Answer (score 1):

The `$1` in your output represents a positional argument such as `["id", 123]`, which includes the `id` you put into your query.

i.e. from the [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-syntax.html):

> A dollar sign ($) followed by digits is used to represent a positional
>   parameter in the body of a function definition or a prepared
>   statement. In other contexts the dollar sign may be part of an
>   identifier or a dollar-quoted string constant.